# Any equivalent function of "logistic" from Stata from R?

Tags: r, stata, logistics

I am trying to do some logistic regression, and having heard that the command `logistic` in Stata can be used to present the coefficient on the OR scale, and `logit` for the same thing in ln(OR) scale. Is there anything equivalent for R? I used `glm` and the output is only ln(OR), so I need to do the calculation all by myself and I am afraid that I may somehow miscalculate something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the help page for predict.glm. Set type="response".

If your interest is only in calculating the OR you would simply enter:

```
exp(coef(fit))
```

Comment: `type=response` gives you probabilities not the odds ratio. You also need to remember to add the intercept coefficient to the variable coefficients before transforming to get the overall prediction.

Comment: The follow on question to getting the odds ratios is often how to get the probabilities. And you are right in pointing out that the R default is to present in the form of treatment contrasts, so that the Intercept is the estimate of the log-odds for the base group, which would be a subject with continuous covariates all = 0 and the factor variables at their lowest levels.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `plogis` (logistic) and `qlogis` (logit)? e.g. `qlogis(0.5)==0`, `plogis(0)==0.5`